# How do I inject a dependency into App?

Tags: ember.js

For example I have this initializer:

```
App.initializer({
  name: "occasional",
  initialize: function(container, application) {
    container.register('occasional:main', application.Occasional, { singleton: true });
    container.typeInjection('controller', 'occasional', 'occasional:main');
  }
});
```

which gives every controller a property `occasional` which refers to a singleton instance of `App.Occasional`.

How do I also give App an `occasional` property refering to the same singleton?

I've tried:

```
container.typeInjection('application:main', 'occasional', 'occasional:main');
```

but it didn't seem to be the magic phrase.

Comment: a question arises, why do you need `occasional` in `App`? Where do you want to use it?

Comment: I need to observe a non-ember property that is checked/observed by several arbitrary controllers. The observer only gets created in certain browsers, and I want to set it up at startup. I could set it up in application controller, and add `needs: 'application'`; the main reason for not doing that first is that I haven't previously needed to open `ApplicationController`.

Comment: I would recommend creating a dedicated object for to handle observing this non-Ember entity and set properties on itself, then inject that object into controllers that need it (or just into all controllers).

Comment: I think it's true that properly I need to open ApplicationController and let it live there. But does anyone know the answer to the actual question?

Comment: I'm pretty good at refactoring, and the code will likely eventually end up where it properly belongs in the object graph. But I posted a question about how to inject a singleton into the App object, because that's what I'm curious to know the answer to.